# y offset annotate text by multiple of font margin / size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to offset the annotation y value by a multiple of the font text margin. (something similar to `em` unit in HTML/CSS).

Of course I could add a epsilon to y argument (trial and error style). But I need to adjust it dynamically because its part of a bigger function.

```
dataA <-
structure(list(dose = c(0.5, 1, 2, 3), len = c(10.605, 19.735, 
26.1, 45), sd = c(4.49976315166172, 4.41543643905882, 3.77415030520987, 
3.3166247903554)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("dose", 
"len", "sd"))
 x="dose";y="len"
```

Ploting

```
p <-ggplot(dataA, aes(x=get(x), y=get(y))) + 
        geom_point(aes(x=get(x), y=get(y)))

p + annotate("text", x = dataA[[x]], y = dataA[[y]], label = c("needs" ,"to go 1,5", "Text-margin up", "Thanks!"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `geom_text()` with arguments `nudge_y` (or `nudge_x` for horizontal offset):

```
dataA$label <- c("needs" ,"to go 1,5", "Text-margin up", "Thanks!")

ggplot(dataA, aes(dose, len)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), nudge_y = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice didnt know about nudge. If no one gives me an `annotate` answer ill mark this as answer.

Comment: nudge seems to be an okay meanwile solution. However it does not exactly what I want.

Comment: what is the difference between `geom_text` and `annotate` in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was originally about `annotate`, which does not know the `nudge_` arguments, here is a solution with this function.

The key is to use the `vjust` argument, which is not clearly shown in the `help`:

```
p + annotate("text", x = dataA[[x]], y = dataA[[y]], 
             label = c("needs" ,"to go 1,5", "Text-margin up", "Thanks!"),
             vjust=-1.5)
```

But indeed, in this specific case since there are several positions to annotate, using `geom_text` is a better way.